# How long does event.preventDefault() last?

Tags: javascript

if you call `preventDefault()` on a `keypress` event for a particular `keyCode`, how long will the default be prevented? Is it for the life of a browser session or only while a particular page is loaded? IS the behaviour for `stopPropagation()` the same?

Some example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[

  function keydownhandler(e)
  {
    switch (e.keyCode)
    {
        case VK_BACK:
                case 461:
        preventDefault();
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
  }


  document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownhandler, true);
]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preventDefault()` prevents a default action to occur, i.e. the browser to post a `form` when enter is pressed. And this default action will be permanently prevented for this instance of the event. Next time `enter` is pressed, you need to prevent that key press to.

`stopPropagation()` stops the event from bubbling down to all elements above the element on which the event occured i.e:

```
<div>
    <a></a>
</div>
```

if you click the `<a>`-tag the div till also get a bubbled `click`-event on it. `stopPropagation()` will prevent this.

EDIT: In your case every event with the `keyCode` == `VK_BACK` or `461` will be prevented to make there default action.

Comment: The question was really about the length of time that this prevention would last.

Comment: For every instance of that specific event, it will be prevented permanently, in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Its prevented permanently for that particular instance of that particular event.

If a key is pressed a 2nd time, this will call a 2nd instance of the `keypress` event, and therefore its default event will not be prevented just because the first event was.

Comment: I am binding all keypress events to an event handler which checks for keyCode values, so thats not true in this case

Comment: It would still be a specific instance of that event handler though?

Comment: The way you are using a function does not change its behaviour, as long as you call `preventDefault` in listener function, it will be prevented.

Comment: @codecowboy It *is* true that the second keypress is not prevented *just because* the first keypress was prevented. They may both be prevented, but there's no direct causal relationship between the first and second (other than the fact that both stem from the same cause).

Comment: @Curt I added some code. The reason for the question is that other developers have put calls to preventDefault() elsewhere in the application

Comment: @codecowboy Shoot, sounds like it's time for me to open a new [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposal. :)

Answer (score 1):

the preventDefault is operated on that event instance that is passed to the handler function, so if you have two inputs with two different "change" event handlers they wont both be stopped if one has the preventDefault.

the stopPropagation is exactly the same as its operating on the event that is passed to the handler.